Bluetooth 32-bit UUID generation / registration
Bluetooth uses 16-bit, 32-bit and 128-bit UUIDs. I can generate 128-bit UUIDs myself of course. I can buy a 16-bit UUID from the Bluetooth SIG.
However, I can't figure out where to get a 32-bit UUID from. Using a random number might result in a collision.
Enlightenement is appreciated.

16-bit and 32-bit are only available from the SIG as they are in the reserved range of xxxxxxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB.  I've had a quick look on the SIG site but I couldn't quickly find a reference on there.

In addition to ukBaz's statement about 32-bit UUIDs. These will be used when the range for 16-bit UUIDs is exhausted. https://support.bluetooth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360062030092-Requesting-Assigned-Numbers

@Risto That makes sense but the page you linked to doesn't contain the number 32, much less a source for your assertion …?

@MatthiasUrlichs I see it the other way round. The page I linked to shows that only 16-bit UUIDs are currently available from the Bluetooth SIG. And on the other hand, any of those 16-bit UUIDs is a perfect 32-bit UUID if you put a 16-bit 0 (0x0000) in front of it.

As ukBaz and Risto stated, 32-bit UUIDs are also pre-assigned by the Bluetooth SIG. This can be found in the Bluetooth Core Specification v5.4, Vol 1, Part E, Section 2.6, Assigned Number Requirements:-

All 16-bit and 32-bit UUIDs as defined in [Vol 3] Part B, Section
2.5.1, are considered assigned numbers. All other UUID values may be used in any context where a UUID is permitted provided they are
generated according to the recommendations in ITU-T Rec.
X.667(10/2012), alternatively known as ISO/IEC 9834.8:2014

And this is the paragraph in Vol 3, Part B, Section 2.5.1 that was referenced above:-

A UUID is a universally unique identifier that is expected to be
unique across all space and all time (more precisely, the probability
of independently-generated UUIDs being the same is negligible). UUIDs
can be independently created in a distributed fashion. No central
registry of assigned UUIDs is required. A UUID is a 128-bit value.
To reduce the burden of storing and transferring 128-bit UUID values,
a range of UUID values has been pre-allocated for assignment to
often-used, registered purposes. The first UUID in this pre-allocated
range is known as the Bluetooth_Base_UUID and has the value
00000000-0000-1000-8000- 00805F9B34FB. UUID values in the
pre-allocated range have aliases that are represented as 16-bit or
32-bit values. These aliases are often called 16-bit and 32-bit UUIDs,
but each actually represents a 128-bit UUID value.

Some reference:-

32-bit UUID supported
Is it illegal to not follow standards regarding UUID


Well, thanks, but my problem is that while theoretically the SIG assigns 32-bit UUIDs, in practice it appears not to, currently. I was hoping that getting a 32-bit UUID would be somewhat cheaper than those 16-bit assignments …

You're right that it’s not immediately clear, but the Bluetooth SIG does indeed handle the assignment/generation of 32-bit UUIDs. Using a self-generated 32-bit UUID will result in your product failing the Bluetooth qualification tests. It’s best to reach out to the Bluetooth SIG directly via the link Risto provided to inquire about pricing, but you can specifically ask about 32-bit UUIDs instead of 16-bit ones.
